# ShimsContext not working from Test Menu

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, microsoft-fakes, shim

We are trying to use ShimsContext for creation of an object and using a property.  It is a normal class(does not inherit from interface/abstract) which cannot be changed.  When we use the example provided in MSDN, we were able to run the tests using Debug->Tests.  When we try to use Test Menu and run Analyze Code Coverage, the tests fail and code coverage is also not showing up properly even though it executes all other tests(which are not using Shims) successfully.  If we select the tests in test explorer, right click and run all the tests including ones using Shimscontext pass and code coverage is showing currently.  Not so sure of this  problem.  Could not find the reason when searched web also.  We have set up a build definition and worried whether the build will run successfully when the code is checked in.  We are using VS 2013,TFS 2013 and .runsettings(it has only code coverage settings configured)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What kind of failure?

Comment: I had something similar when my VS used custom settings. Make sure your VS doesn't use any custom test settings....

Comment: It is trying to access the original class instead of shim